# Remove some keys from an array inside another array in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How to remove some keys from an array inside another array in PHP?
I have this structure:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'num' => '123',
    'nome' => 'test 001'
    'pontos' => 68,
    'data_status' => '03/09/2021 10:05',
    'uuid_status' => '69450ea451ae11ea85ca309c23d3a0ed'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'num' => '345',
    'nome' => 'test 002'
    'pontos' => 120,
    'data_status' => '27/08/2021 15:46',
    'uuid_status' => '3cbf4fd15d5411ea86956eef5d66cb13',
  ),
)
```

and need to return something like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'num' => '123',
    'nome' => 'test 001'
    'pontos' => 68
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'num' => '345',
    'nome' => 'test 002'
    'pontos' => 120
  )
)
```

I've seen some answers but they seem to be outdated, also i'm using Laravel, so it would help if someone point me out something from the framework and its equivalent in pure PHP

Comment: _...I've seen some answers but they seem to be outdated..._ What is wrong with those answers? What have you been trying on your own? What issues are you facing?

Comment: Please remember Laravel is just a framework. It all balances on PHP so anything Laravel is by definition PHP

Comment: can someone point me out a correct one? i tried Arr::only helper from Laravel with return this: return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip((array) $keys)); But I coudn't get it to work because array inside array and I don't know how

Comment: Do you want to delete items from this array or create a new array without the items you dont want

Comment: Does this come from a query? If so you could just select which columns you want at that point instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple foreach loop is a good starting point, note this will remove items from the original array, by using the reference `&` to the array rather than a normal simple copy. On the `$val` in the `foreach ( $input as &$val){`

```
$input = [
    [   
        'num' => '123',
        'nome' => 'test 001',
        'pontos' => 68,
        'data_status' => '03/09/2021 10:05',
        'uuid_status' => '69450ea451ae11ea85ca309c23d3a0ed'
    ],[
        'num' => '345',
        'nome' => 'test 002',
        'pontos' => 120,
        'data_status' => '27/08/2021 15:46',
        'uuid_status' => '3cbf4fd15d5411ea86956eef5d66cb13'
    ]
];

$remove = ['data_status','uuid_status'];

foreach ( $input as &$val){
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        if ( in_array($k,$remove) ) {
            unset( $val[$k]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($input);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [num] => 123
            [nome] => test 001
            [pontos] => 68
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [num] => 345
            [nome] => test 002
            [pontos] => 120
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most concise, but it gets the job done:

```
$bad_keys = array('data_status', 'uuid_status');




$array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'num' => '123',
    'nome' => 'test 001',
    'pontos' => 68,
    'data_status' => '03/09/2021 10:05',
    'uuid_status' => '69450ea451ae11ea85ca309c23d3a0ed',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'num' => '345',
    'nome' => 'test 002',
    'pontos' => 120,
    'data_status' => '27/08/2021 15:46',
    'uuid_status' => '3cbf4fd15d5411ea86956eef5d66cb13',
  ),
);


function traverse_array($array, $bad_keys) {


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        
            if (is_array($value)) {
            
                    $array[$key] = traverse_array($value, $bad_keys);
            
            } else {
            
                    foreach ($bad_keys as $remove_me) {
            
                            if ($key == $remove_me) {
                
                                unset($array[$key]);
                    
                                }
                    }
        }
        
     }
     
     return $array;
}

print_r(traverse_array($array, $bad_keys));
```

Comment: this will handle multidimensional arrays, no matter how deep they go

Comment: Please format your code and add proper indentation to it. Sidenote: you can just use the modern way of defining an array by doing `$bad_keys = ['data_status', 'uuid_status'];`  Same applies to all your arrays

Comment: by modern, do you mean over 7 years old?

Comment: You've forgotten to reformat your question.  _..by modern, do you mean over 7 years old?_ Yes, absolutely! Wondering if you are aware of the 7 years, why do you still use the stone age notation

Comment: it's not stone age, it still how the php docs present it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php   neither way is wrong, especially when i was using the format the op used....